# How to open in a new window for a submit button?

Tags: yii2, active-form

Is it possible to open in a new window when i click a submit button ? I have TWO SUBMIT buttons in my active form.

I know if i give `'target'=>'_blank'` i will get the desired result in normal cases but it didn't work in active form.

```
 <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-6">
            <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? Yii::t('app', 'Submit') : Yii::t('app', 'Update'), ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <?= Html::submitButton('Pdf', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary','name'=>'Pdf'],['target'=>'_blank']) ?>
            </div>
        </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

I tried as above. then i decided to give `target => _blank` to active form as shown below

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(
    ['options'=>['target'=>'_blank']]); ?>
```

It works but not in the desired way. Now if i click on any one of the buttons i will be redirected to new page. I only want to get redirected to new page when i click on button 'Pdf'. 
Any Ideas?

I don't want any javascript to be used.

Comment: but why you are using two submit buttons?

Comment: because for my purpose i need two submit buttons :-)

Comment: what do you want to submit using two buttons?

Answer (score 1):

You can use anchor for new window.

```
<?= Html::a('Pdf', 'url', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary','name'=>'Pdf', 'target'=>'_blank']) ?>
```

Comment: hi i am using a submit button can't use a normal html button

Comment: anyway...you can use above button.

Comment: i am using one Submit button to get dates and other button to get pdf of the view

Answer (score 1):

```
form = ActiveForm::begin(
       ['options'=>['target'=>'_blank']]);
```

it needs to work

Comment: When you answered a question please try to explain how it solves the problem.  Visit and check [how to answer a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you very mutch! Gracefull solution!